# flash - spark Image width = 100%, height = auto

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, adobe, flex-spark

How to scale the image, whatever it takes 100% width and height proportions retained?
In html and css is done simply width: 100%; height: auto
And in the flash image leaves margins at the top and bottom, when scaled proportionally

Here is my code:

```
<s:Image id="bannerImage" width="100%" useHandCursor="true" fillMode="scale" verticalAlign="middle" scaleMode="letterbox" smooth="true" smoothingQuality="high" />
```

That's what turns around:

[image]

Red rectangles - the space that remains when scaled as get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

By default Image will scale the graphics so that they maintain their aspect ratio.

You can configure this behaviour through the [scaleMode](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/Image.html#scaleMode) property.
The default value is [BitmapScaleMode.LETTERBOX](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/graphics/BitmapScaleMode.html#LETTERBOX)
If you want the graphics to stretch, use [BitmapScaleMode.STRETCH](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/graphics/BitmapScaleMode.html#STRETCH) instead.

```
<s:Image source="@Embed('/myImage.png')" 
         scaleMode="stretch" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

Comment: I need to preserve the aspect ratio, but that would not be left empty margins at the top and bottom

Comment: I already tried all combinations of attributes and scaleMode fillMode. Niodin option does not give the desired result

Comment: @jeka5555 That doesn't make any sense: if the container has a different shape than the image, and the image must maintain its aspect ratio, then you _will_ have margins (whether your technology is html/css, Flex or whatever).

Comment: no, css / html in the picture does not remain in the fields, and here they are (the image is not reduced in height)

Comment: @jeka5555 I think you didn't understand me correctly. If the container of the image has a certain height that is bigger than that of the image, then there must be margins (doesn't have anything to do with technology; it's just math). Perhaps your problem lies with the container rather than the image itself, but I can't tell from the one line of code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Complete code mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
buttonMode="true"
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"

initialize="init()">

<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[

    import core.Application;
    import core.media.Manager;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import spark.components.RichEditableText;
    import spark.components.RichText;
    import flashx.textLayout.conversion.TextConverter;

    private var bannerID:String;
    private var bannerData:Object;

    // Init banner to show
    // -------------------
    public function init():void {

        // If no any banners, return
        // -------------------------
        if (Application.storage.banners == null) return;

        // Count banners
        // -------------
        var count:Number = 0;
        var banners:Array = new Array();
        for (var itemIndex:String in Application.storage.banners) banners.push(itemIndex);

        // Select any random
        // -----------------
        var bannerIndex:Number = Math.round(Math.random() * (banners.length - 1));
        this.bannerID = banners[bannerIndex];
        this.bannerData = Application.storage.banners[bannerID];

        // If banner non exists, return
        // ----------------------------
        var bannerFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath('data/banners/' + this.bannerID + '.jpg');
        if (! bannerFile.exists) return;

        // Else, banner is exists
        // ----------------------
        Manager.lazyLoad(this.bannerImage, bannerFile);     

    }

    // Open banner inside popup
    // ------------------------
    private function openBanner():void {

        // If no text data, return
        // -----------------------
        if (bannerData.text == null) return;

        // Create text object
        // ------------------
        var bannerText:RichEditableText = new RichEditableText();
        bannerText.percentWidth = 100;
        bannerText.lineBreak = 'toFit';
        bannerText.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(bannerData.text, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);

        // Show popup
        // ----------
        ui.Popup.show(bannerText);

    }

]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Image id="bannerImage" width="100%" height="100%" click="openBanner()" useHandCursor="true" fillMode="scale" verticalAlign="middle" scaleMode="letterbox"  smooth="true" smoothingQuality="high" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BitmapImage instead of Image with scaleMode="letterbox".